# Unable to decrypt: RSA_R_PADDING_CHECK_FAILED - OpenSSL 1.1.0‏

Tags: c, windows, encryption, openssl

I'm creating a simple utility to encrypt and decrypt files using a key pair. I'm on Windows and coding against the 1.1.0 version of Openssl. I can load the key pair and encrypt the file fine, but when I try to decrypt EVP_PKEY_decrypt always returns -1. I traced this to the rsa padding check functions and they are returning -1 but I can't figure out why. I've tried changing the padding from RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING  to RSA_PKCS1_PADDING and still have the same problem. Any insight would be appreciated, here are my encrypt and decrypt functions:

```
#define FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH 1
#define ENC_BUFFER_LENGTH 2048

int encryptfile(EVP_PKEY *key, FILE *srcfp, FILE *tgtfp) {

    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key, NULL);
    char *inbuf;
    unsigned char *outbuf;
    size_t in_len = 0;
    size_t out_len = ENC_BUFFER_LENGTH;
    int x;

    inbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH+1);
    outbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*ENC_BUFFER_LENGTH+1);

    if (ctx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while creating encryption context.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(ctx) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while initializing encryption context.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while setting encryption padding.\n");
        return 0;
    }



    while (1) {
        in_len = fread(inbuf, 1, FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH, srcfp);

        if (in_len == 0) {break;}

        if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, outbuf, &out_len, inbuf, in_len) <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while encrypting data.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        x = fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(char), in_len, tgtfp);

        if (x != in_len) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing to target file.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}


int decryptfile(EVP_PKEY *key, FILE *srcfp, FILE *tgtfp) {

    ENGINE *e = ENGINE_new();
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key, NULL);
    unsigned char *inbuf;
    unsigned char *outbuf;
    size_t in_len = 0;
    size_t out_len = ENC_BUFFER_LENGTH;
    int x;

    inbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH + 1);
    outbuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*ENC_BUFFER_LENGTH + 1);

    if (ctx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while creating decryption context.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while initializing decryption context.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while setting decryption padding.\n");
        return 0;
    }



    while (1) {
        in_len = fread(inbuf, 1, FILE_BUFFER_LENGTH, srcfp);

        if (in_len == 0) { break; }

        if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, outbuf, &out_len, inbuf, in_len) <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while decrypting data.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        x = fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(char), in_len, tgtfp);

        if (x != in_len) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing decrypted data to target file.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }


    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be writing out_len bytes rather than in_len bytes?

Comment: @immibis where at?

Comment: At both the places you call `fwrite`

Comment: @immibis that did the trick, thanks again, feel free to type it up as an answer, however I see you don't need the points so if you don't I will :-)

Comment: Same thing with the `if`s following the `fwrite`s. But there are more errors.

Comment: @CristiFati yeah I fixed those too after following the logic, thanks though. Do you see more errors?

Comment: Yes. When processing the encrypted file you read (and try to decrypt ) 1 byte at a time. That can't work. Have you tried with an input file larger than 128 bytes?

Comment: Oh, yes fixed that too (that was a long 15 minutes :-) ), I haven't tried it with a file that big, but decrypting that file that was encrypted 1 byte at a time did fail indeed, so I upped the buffer to 2048, and will be trying to encrypt a large file next. Thanks for the second set of eyes @CristiFati